# How to call UploadHandler.php with PHP - blueimp jQuery File Upload

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

Does anyone know how to upload images using PHP and calling the UploadHandler.php?

I'm not sure what information needs to be passed and in what format.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$prop="test";
session_id($prop);
@session_start();
$url = 'http://christinewilson.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/port_rhdefence.png';
$file_name[] = file_get_contents($url);

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler(array(
    'user_dirs' => true
));
```

Comment: by default its set `'param_name' => 'files'` in the class construct, so i guess it expects `<input type="file" name="files" />`

Comment: Thanks I'm going to look into this more. When it sends "files" do you know what its actually sending? Is it the equivalent of file_get_contents in PHP?

Comment: No it will fill your `$_FILES` array with the path to the file and info. You access that in the same way as any other array e.g: `$_FILES['files']`. Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 4):

The response is contained within the UploadHandler class object and can be retrieved like shown below.

```
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
$response = $upload_handler->response;
$files = $response['files'];
$file_count = count($files);
for ($c = 0; $c < $file_count; $c++) {
   if (isset($files[$c]->error))
       continue;
   $type = $files[$c]->type;
   $name = $files[$c]->name;
   $url = $files[$c]->url;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a way to get the file name via php so I had to do it myself.

First you need to add a public variable under UploadHandler.php

```
class UploadHandler
{
    public $file_name;
    protected $options;
```

and then add that to the function that creates the name

```
protected function get_file_name($name,
        $type = null, $index = null, $content_range = null) {

    $this->file_name = $this->get_unique_filename(
        $this->trim_file_name($name, $type, $index, $content_range),
        $type,
        $index,
        $content_range
    );
    return $this->file_name;
}
```

then under index.php you could do something like this

```
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
echo "\r\n [" . $upload_handler->fileName . "]\r\n";
```

I hope this help you or save someone some time :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use [the basic plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="server/php/" multiple>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: This uses jquery to call UploadHandler class unless I'm missing something here. I'm looking to call the class with PHP instead.

Comment: As the name of the plugin says, you need jQuery to upload a file

Comment: Thanks Dirty-flow but I was looking for a way to not use jQuery and call the UploadHandler class with PHP only.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, where in the PHP I wanted to write all the URLS that UploadHandler.php had created to a mySQL database.  If you look through the code, you'll see that

```
public function post($print_response = true)
```

actually returns the data structure from generate_response (which is a array with all the processed image metadata like image size, sanitized url, etc), but the call to $this->post() never does anything which it.  So I add a variable

```
protected $upload_content = [];
```

to the class definition and changed the logic in function

```
protected function initialize()
```

to

```
        case 'POST':
             $this->upload_content = $this->post(false);
             break;
```

to update this variable after the images have been processed (you would need to do something similar with the GET case if you are using that).  Then, I add a public function to the class to get this variable

```
 public function get_upload_content() {
     return $this->upload_content;
 }
```

and now the UploadHandler class can be called like this

```
 $upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
 $images = $upload_handler->get_upload_content();
 // Call a function that writes the urls in $images array to a database
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create protected variable:

```
protected $options;
protected $uploaded_files = [];
```

then you should assign to this variable the response value in post() method:

```
$this->uploaded_files = $response;
return $this->generate_response($response, $print_response);
```

then you should create public method which would return that response:

```
public function get_uploaded_files() {
        return $this->uploaded_files;
    }
```

and finally you should initiate the class and call the method:

```
$uploadPicture = new UploadHandler();
        $images = $uploadPicture->get_uploaded_files();
```

Hope this Helps !